# Python OpenCV - Trouble detecting tiny "holes" (circles)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-recognition

I'm trying to detect "holes" in a drawing, that is to say, they aren't quite circles, they're of varying size. The images are always black and white. Just trying to get my head around this problem, I took an example from the Python documentation:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import *
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('hole_test.jpg',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,5,param1=200,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # pinpoint hole
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)     
cv2.imshow('holes detected',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The holes detected are few and far between. Is there anything I can do to improve the accuracy of this example, or is this not the best way to achieve this?

This is an example image, simply to show the various size/shape of "holes" I'm aiming to find.

[image: example image]

Example 2 as requested

[image: Example 2 as requested:]

Comment: Pattern recognition could potentially work on this, have you tried it?

Comment: No, I've yet to find an example of this. The example image here is simply to illustrate the sizes and shapes of the "holes" I'm trying to find within images.

Comment: Do any of your images contain things that aren't holes that you want to avoid detecting?

Comment: @MrE yes, many of the images contain gome grids of lines, these are straight and don't contain "holes". Edit, that is to say, it's not as simple as detecting anything which isn't black.

Comment: maybe you can post the image which contains grids of lines because for the given image it seems as simple as detecting anything which isn't black

Comment: @ZawLin Poste updated with another example showing common features of source images

Comment: also you might wanna look @ a matlab implementation(http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9168-detect-circles-with-various-radii-in-grayscale-image-via-hough-transform). results @ http://i.stack.imgur.com/J9rQm.jpg. with some tuning and patience, very good accuracy seems possible

Comment: have you tried a contour-based approach? simply remove all contours with area larger than certain threshold and only holes will remain

Comment: @ZawLin I don't have matlab I'm afraid, though the results seem good. I'll need to do some research on a countour based approach, I've never attempted anything like this before. Really starting from the ground floor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = cv2.imread('holes2.jpg')

gray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray=cv2.threshold(gray,20,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imshow('gray',gray)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray,cv2.RETR_LIST ,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE   )

for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area<400:
        cv2.drawContours(im,[cnt],0,(255,0,0),2)

cv2.imshow('im',im)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Perfect, I can move on with the remainder of the task. Thank you for this example and all your efforts.